# ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, git-push

**Cuando hago:**

```
git push origin master
```

**Estoy teniendo este error:**

> ERROR: Repository not found.
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

**La salida de `git remote -v` es:**

```
origin  git@github.com:username/repositorio.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/repositorio.git (push)
```

**La salida de `ssh -T git@github.com`**

> Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953071/github-authentication-failed-github-does-not-provide-shell-access) puede que te sirva :D

Answer (score 0):

Se debe tener en cuenta los permisos que se tengan en Github ya que la cuenta configurada en el git local debe concordar con la que tiene permisos en el Github.